# Join data frames over a third dimension by row/column names

Tags: r

I have an arbitrary number of data frames, with row and column names.

My goal is to join those data frames using row/column names as join key, over a third dimension, ie, I want the result to be a named three dimensional array.

My problem is that I don't want to join them **positionally** but by their row/column names.

I know I can use **abind()** for concatenating arrays along any desired dimension, but abind concatenates data **positionally**, not by dimname.

In sql terms, I want a full join using row/column names as join keys, but along a third dimension.

Here you have a small reproducible example with only two data frames:

```
first <- data.frame(one=c(1,2), two=c(3,4), row.names = c("one", "two"))
second <- data.frame(one=c(10,20), three=c(50,60), row.names = c("one", "three"))
result <- someMagicFunction(first, second)
```

My desired output for the "result" object is:

```
result <- array(data=c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       10, NA, 20, NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, 60), 
                dim = c(3, 3, 2), 
                dimnames = list(
                  c("one", "two", "three"),
                  c("one", "two", "three"),
                  c("first", "second")))
> result
, , first

      one two three
one     1   3    NA
two     2   4    NA
three  NA  NA    NA

, , second

      one two three
one    10  NA    50
two    NA  NA    NA
three  20  NA    60
```

I have written a function by myself to accomplish the task, but I would like to know if there is already any built-in function to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using `arrays`? I mean it's quite unusual to join on column and row names, or?

Comment: Why not just reorder the rows/columns so they are in the appropriate order and then use `abind`?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(abind)
library(magrittr)

in.dfs <- list(first, second)

cols <- unique(unlist(lapply(in.dfs, names)))
rows <- unique(unlist(lapply(in.dfs, rownames)))

allNA <- 
  matrix(NA, length(cols), length(rows)) %>% 
    `colnames<-`(cols) %>% 
    `rownames<-`(rows)

lapply(in.dfs, function(df){
  allNA[rownames(df), names(df)] <- as.matrix(df)
  allNA
}) %>% 
  list(along = 3) %>% 
  do.call(what = abind)
```

Result

```
# , , 1
# 
#       one two three
# one     1   3    NA
# two     2   4    NA
# three  NA  NA    NA
# 
# , , 2
# 
#       one two three
# one    10  NA    50
# two    NA  NA    NA
# three  20  NA    60
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear about the "array" thing. I would solve it like this:

If you are looking for a *quick*, *base* and *elegant* solution:

data:

```
first <- data.frame(one=c(1,2), two=c(3,4), row.names = c("one", "two"))
second <- data.frame(one=c(10,20), three=c(50,60), row.names = c("one", "three"))

l <- list(first, second)
```

code:

```
dn <- unique(c(sapply(l, names)))

model<-as.data.frame(structure(rep(NA,length(dn)^2), .Dim = c(length(dn), length(dn)), .Dimnames = list(dn, dn)))

lapply(l, function(el){model[names(el),names(el)] <- el;model})
```

result:

```
[[1]]
      one two three
one     1   3    NA
two     2   4    NA
three  NA  NA    NA

[[2]]
      one two three
one    10  NA    50
two    NA  NA    NA
three  20  NA    60
```